# Properly configure the dashboard in Opserver

Tags: c#, .net, opserver

This question pertains to Stack Exchange's Opserver monitoring suite: https://github.com/opserver/Opserver

Most of the configuration files in Opserver are straight forward.  However, one section that I am having trouble figuring out how to configure is the dashboard.

Here is a snippet of the **DashboardSetting.json.example** file:

```
{
    ... 

    "providers": [
        {
            "name": "Orion",
            "type": "Orion",
            "host": "orion.ds.stackexchange.com",
            "connectionString": "Data Source=ny-utilsql01;Initial Catalog=SolarWindsOrion;Integrated Security=SSPI;Timeout=10"
        }
    ]
}
```

From what I can gather, this "Orion" provider type has a supporting data structure that lives inside of a SQL database and that, once pointed to, provides information pertaining to the servers to monitor.

The problem that I'm having is that I don't have much of an idea how to set this up in my environment.  I haven't been able to locate any DB setup scripts to run or documentation describing the setup of the dashboard.

Comment: Quick answer: Orion is a product by SolarWinds that opserver has a provider for...hopefully the first provider of many.  We will be writing our own monitoring solution and of course well have a provider for that, but hopefully many more from the community as well.  I'll do a full answer tomorrow as time allows, but didn't want this hanging all night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Dashboard feature currently appears to be specific to data retrieved from an application called SolarWinds Orion. [The source code leaves room](https://github.com/opserver/Opserver/blob/957a0296fda3662be1fd5683682075c970824154/Opserver.Core/Data/Dashboard/DashboardData.cs) for additional dashboard data source plugins, but that is the only one currently provided by default.

You may turn off the dashboard (it is not required) by disabling that config file if you do not have that product. Opserver offers many optional features. Enable the ones that fit your network topology.